# soundManager2: Cannot Preload All Of My Sounds From Arrays Of Urls

Tags: javascript, audio

What I'm essentially attempting to build, is a site that reads itself, and provides audible feedback when the mouse is used. Earcons are used in a similar way to how most users work with visual icons. Prerecorded spoken tracks are used for known elements, such as my nag bar menu. I'm using E-Speak for tts in most browsers, but plan to use a tts web service in IE, as E-Speak does not work in IE. Traditionally, a blind user would navigate a site with keystrokes; but, I'm a web developer in training, and I'm pushing the envelope by using sounds as an aid to proofing layout [i.e] are my divs floating correctly? Is an image in the correct div? I can check this by mousing around and listening. It's something of a disruptive technology, which tries to give your mind's eye more credit than it gets using a more conventional read solution.

I have been at this for weeks, still cannot preload all of my sounds. I've resorted to a recursive function which, in theory, will not create the next sound object until the first one has loaded. My eighteen earcons are loading and playing correctly on the desired events, but only three of my 12 spoken tracks appear to be loading--or, if they are loading, they are not playing.

Here's the code for my two relevant modules. Have any of you come up with a reliable method of preloading multiple sounds?

```
var Earcons = (function() {
   // Earcons are like icons, but use symbolic sounds instead of pictures
 var trackUrls = [
 "audio/newpage.mp3", "audio/fgrow.mp3", "audio/fshrink.mp3",
 "audio/slideright.mp3", "audio/slideleft.mp3", "audio/sdiv.mp3", "audio/tell.mp3",
 "audio/office_lobby.mp3", "audio/footstep.mp3", "audio/apple.mp3",
 "audio/typewriter.mp3",
 "audio/walking.mp3", "audio/macspeak.mp3", "audio/picklock1.mp3",
 "audio/gossip.mp3", "audio/winenter.mp3", "audio/winleave.mp3", "audio/beep.mp3"];

 var trackTitles = [
 "soundOnLoad", "soundOnGrow", "soundOnShrink", "soundOnSlideRight",
 "soundOnSlideLeft", "soundOnDiv", "soundOnParagraph", "work",
 "soundOnList", "apple", "stype", "walk", "macbook",
 "soundOnLink", "soundOnInput", "winenter", "winleave", "soundOnImage"];

 var trackPtr = 0;

 var getTrackNumber = function (trackName) {
   for (i = 0; i < trackTitles.length; i++) {
     if (trackName == trackTitles[i]) return i;
   }
   return -1;
 };

 var preload = function() {
   if (trackPtr >= trackUrls.length)
   { trackPtr = 0; return; }
   var trackId = "st" + trackPtr + "";
   var trackUrl = trackUrls[trackPtr];
   trackPtr++;
   var soundTrack = soundManager.createSound ({stream: false,
   id: trackId,
   url: trackUrl,
   autoLoad: false, autoPlay: false});
   soundTrack.load ({onload: function() { preload(); } });
 };

 var unload = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < trackUrls.length; i++) {
     var soundTrack = soundManager.getSoundById ("st" + i);
     soundTrack.unload();
     soundTrack.destruct();
   }
 };

 interface = {
   trackUrls: trackUrls,
   trackTitles: trackTitles,
   getTrackNumber: getTrackNumber,
   preload: preload,
   unload: unload
 };


  return interface;

} )();

 var Narrations = (function() {
  var trackUrls = [
  "audio/about.mp3", "audio/webtech.mp3", "audio/screenreader.mp3",
 "audio/services.mp3", "audio/stories.mp3", "audio/settings.mp3",
  "audio/feedback.mp3", "audio/display.mp3", "audio/soundset.mp3",
  "audio/voiceset.mp3", "audio/divmain.mp3", "audio/divcenter.mp3",
 "audio/divnav.mp3"];

 var trackTitles = [
 "About This Web App", "Web Development Technologies", "What's A Screen Reader",
 "Services I Can Offer", "Stories, Poetry, Anecdotes", "Settings",
 "Send Me Your Comments", "Display Settings", "Sound Settings",
 "Voice Quality Settings", "div mainContent", "div center", "div navBar"];

 var trackPtr = 0;

 var getTrackNumber = function (trackName) {
   for (i = 0; i < trackTitles.length; i++) {
     if (trackName == trackTitles[i]) return i;
   }
   return -1;
 };

 var preload = function() {
   if (trackPtr >= trackUrls.length)
   { trackPtr = 0; return; }
   var trackId = "vt" + trackPtr + "";
   var trackUrl = trackUrls[trackPtr];
   trackPtr++;
   var voiceTrack = soundManager.createSound ({stream: false,
   id: trackId,
   url: trackUrl,
   autoLoad: false, autoPlay: false});
   voiceTrack.load ({onload: function() { preload(); } });
 };

 var unload = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < trackUrls.length; i++) {
     var voiceTrack = soundManager.getSoundById ("vt" + i);
     voiceTrack.unload();
     voiceTrack.destruct();
   }
 };


 interface = {
   trackUrls: trackUrls,
   trackTitles: trackTitles,
   getTrackNumber: getTrackNumber,
   preload: preload,
   unload: unload
 };

 return interface;
})();
```

The function for playing the ear cons:
    var playSound = function (trackName) {
     var trackID = "st" + Earcons.getTrackNumber (trackName) + "";
     var soundTrack = soundManager.getSoundById (trackID);
     if ( !soundTrack) return;
      if (silent) return;
      if (soundManager.playState > 0) soundManager.stopAll();
       soundTrack.play();
    };

and for playing the spoken recordings:
     function playSpeech (recording) {
       var tn = Narrations.getTrackNumber (recording);
       if (tn == -1) return false;
       var voiceId = "vt" + tn + "";
       var voiceTrack = soundManager.getSoundById (voiceId);
       if ( !voiceTrack) return false;
       if (soundManager.playState > 0) soundManager.stopAll();
       soundManager.onready (function() { voiceTrack.play(); });
     return true;
    }     // end playSpeech

Might it all work better if I make the play functions methods [i.e] Earcons.playSound(), Narrations.playSpeech()?
You can experience the working parts of my site in action at:
www.innovascripter.com
Thanks in advance for any insight :-)

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 has a hardware and resource determined limit on how many audio tags can be loaded at once.  I work on [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), and we include notes on this and other limitations in our [documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/modules/SoundJS.html).

SoundJS has two workarounds for this, the recently implemented [audio sprites](http://blog.createjs.com/audio-sprite-support-in-soundjs/) and the older solution of forcing flash fallback.

Hope that helps.